# why Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startupOracle); does not fully execute command

Tags: java, sql, oracle, runtime, listener

I'm beginner at java and have some issues trying to startup oracle with java code. I've read several topics about this theme but none of them worked for me. Here is my code:

```
try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String host = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
            String uName = "username";
            String uPass = "password";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass); 

    }catch (Exception err){

        }
        if (con == null){
       String[] startupOracle = new String[]{"cmd ", " /c start cmd /K " + "\"" + " chcp 1251 "
         + " &C:\\app\\Raph\\product\\12.1.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus.exe " + "username/password" 
            + "&startup" };

       Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startupOracle); 
        }
```

I have two issues:

1. The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startupOracle);` execute till the point of login me in and stops execution immediately after I'm logged in thereby leaving line 15 ("&startup") not executed.
2. I'm unable to connect to oracle using `"CONNECT / AS SYSDBA"` as my username. I guess this is due to the empty space and `"/"` character in the username because when I use "system" as my username I get connected. I don't know how to solve the issue of empty space and `"/"` in the former username.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc of [`exec(String[] cmdarray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) says:

> **Parameters:**
>   `cmdarray` - array containing the command to call and its arguments.

Its "arguments" *(plural)*, which means if you want to execute command `foo.exe bar abc`, then you need to pass `{ "foo.exe", "bar", "abc" }`, not `{ "foo.exe", "bar abc" }`.

For your code that means:

```
String[] startupOracle = new String[] {
        "cmd",
        "/c",
        "start",
        "cmd",
        "/K",
        "\"chcp 1251" +
          " & " +
          "C:\\app\\Raph\\product\\12.1.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus.exe username/password &startup\""
};
```

Or something like that, though I think you have some problems with the `&`'s.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I later figured out the issue. There was no issue with my code, I had to add startup command to glogin.sql file and that solved my problem.